# Flutter's main.dart file gets stuck at "Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64..." at execution in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

I am trying out my first ever flutter code on Android Studio and I am displaying it on an emulator.
I do get the output but the compilation never ends, which means I cannot Hot Restart my code. The tutorial I am learning from isn't getting this problem.

**EDIT** : Some new errors arose. It started hanging at "Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk", I solved that issue and now it displays this.
It is intermittent, the skipped frame and lines interchange but more or less the problem remains the same. Please help am going crazy over solving it :)

The following code appears:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64...
I/Choreographer( 5985): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation( 5985): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7e7ece03e300: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7e7ece1a85e0)
I/OpenGLRenderer( 5985): Davey! duration=1554ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=1503595359014, Vsync=1504612025640, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1504619561700, AnimationStart=1504619633200, PerformTraversalsStart=1504619653300, DrawStart=1504626010200, SyncQueued=1504626824700, SyncStart=1504630541800, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1504630721200, SwapBuffers=1504690106800, FrameCompleted=1505153649500, DequeueBufferDuration=49170000, QueueBufferDuration=2336000, 
D/EGL_emulation( 5985): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7e7ecc6fa7e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7e7ecc62baa0)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64...
```

Comment: Do you know any workaround?

Comment: I am using 'Debug' option to run my code. Its seems normal, the StatelessWidget class also let's my code without Hot Restart.

Comment: This solution worked for me....
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61151567/3888834

Answer (score 4):

Well, it seems on Linux that's because of some changes in kernel 5.5. I tested multiple times and I am sure - on kernel 5.4 it works, but on kernel 5.5 refactoring hangs and also debug does not work.

That's strange, I have no idea how is is related to kernel (refactoring? wtf?), I can suspect some changes in filsestem handling could cause that? Need to create bug report to InteliJ or Flutter and tell them new kernel causes problem.

Also strange, when developing in Java/Kotlin with Android Studio, I have no problems, refactoring and debug both work just fine. So this must be related to Flutter.

So, on Linux need to downgrade kernel to 5.4 for now (no idea about Mac or Win).

Comment: Working on Windows. I have been managing to run it in debug mode on my AVD. It is quite intermittent, though hot reloading solves my problems for now and I have no idea why or how.

Comment: What distro are you on?  same problem here on Arch. 
upgraded to kernel 5.5 this morning then flutter got stuck on Syncing files. I'm on  flutter stable , also tried master, problem still there. 
downgraded kernel to 5.4  now its working again ..

Comment: Debian. But distro does not matter, only kernel version matters

Comment: Tweaked a few things, let me know if you can address this issue, working on Android Studio btw. @user1209216

Comment: You can't do anything to solve this issue, either downgrade kernel or wait for fix at Flutter's side

Answer (score 1):

Put this statement right after the beginning of main function.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

And then restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

i experienced this problem when i was not connected to net.And I was running that project for the first time.So check your internet and restart the app couple of time it will run fast

Comment: I have a working internet connection, doesn't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Only agreeing with [user1209216](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955690/flutters-main-dart-file-gets-stuck-at-syncing-files-to-device-android-sdk-buil/60000282#60000282).

Using Visual Studio, execution was stuck on "Syncing files to device" while using kernel-5.5.8-200.fc31.

I downgraded to kernel-5.3.7-301.fc31 and was able to launch a Flutter app on an emulator and a physical device.

See also: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/

You can either downgrade to a previous kernel until a new version of Flutter is released on the stable channel or run `flutter channel master`.

More information on how Flutter structures their release channels: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error in my Fedora which is running on the Linux kernel (5.11). I tried several things but nothing worked. It was taking 2-3 forced restart to finish the build.

I downgraded the emulator API from API level 30 (x86) to API level 28 (x86_64) now it is working seamlessly on my machine. Build of a small app only takes 1 minute or so. If nothing worked for you, therefore, you may try downgrading the API level of the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

I have an exactly same issue on linux5.5 kernel.

inxi

```
CPU: Quad Core AMD Ryzen 3 PRO 3300U w/ Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (-MCP-) 
speed/max: 1397/1400 MHz Kernel: 5.5.2-1-MANJARO x86_64 Up: 1d 4h 05m 
Mem: 12541.8/22014.1 MiB (57.0%) Storage: 476.94 GiB (15.3% used) Procs: 332 
Shell: fish 3.0.2 inxi: 3.0.37
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same situation today, and took me a few hours to find out the solution, and it was very simple.

I basically started building a loop, then got distracted with something else, and forgot to delete it.

So what caused my "Syncing files to device" not to finish, and my initial page to freeze, was this. I had an infinite loop in my Home initState.